# Changing UI Elements in Android by using Callbacks and Handlers

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner, android-button, android-handler

I've got a problem I believe the solution is relatively simple but I'm missing something. Basically the flow of my program from the user side is that I have a "home screen" of sorts where the on screen buttons are translucent and unresponsive until an item is selected from a drop down menu (spinner widget). 
On the code side, I've defined the layout in an XML file and then just write all of the associated in Java. So in the onCreate() method I've initialized the buttons like so:

```
public void initButtons() {
        Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_two);
        Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_three);
        Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_four);

        buttonOne.setClickable(false);
        buttonTwo.setClickable(false);
        buttonThree.setClickable(false);
        buttonFour.setClickable(false);

        buttonOne.setAlpha(0.5f);
        ButtonTwo.setAlpha(0.5f);
        buttonThree.setAlpha(0.5f);
        buttonFour.setAlpha(0.5f);
    }
```

That works fine, but I want to set some onClickListeners AFTER an item has been selected from my spinner. So my activity class implements onItemClickListener and I've got the following callbacks in my code:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    if (position != 0) {
        selectedTown = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        CharSequence text = "You've Selected " + selectedItem;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SampleUI.this, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        itemSelected = true;
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    } else { 
        itemSelected = false;
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
```

The boolean itemSelected is of global scope within the activity class, the Toast is for debugging purposes and not essential. But the problem i have is when I try to change the buttons after an item on the spinner (below position 0) has been selected. I have a message handler defined like so:

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if ((itemSelected == true) && (buttonsActivated == false)) {
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SampleUI.this,"Activating Buttons", duration);
                toast.show();
                activateButtons();
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
```

This handler works properly until I call the activateButtons() method which goes something like this:

```
public void activateButtons() {
        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Code to respond to buttonClick
            }
        });
}
```

Whenever I try to interact with the UI elements in either one of the callbacks or the handler, I get a Java NULL pointer exception. I'm pretty sure it's something rather simple and fundamental I've missed, but I cannot seem to spot the problem. If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear from you :)
Will S-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare all UI elements at Class level instead of inside method as:

```
//********** DELCARE ALL UI ELEMETS HERE ******

    Button buttonOne,buttonTwo,buttonThree,buttonFour;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initButtons(); 
      }

    public void initButtons() {
          buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
          buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_two);
          buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_three);
          buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_four);
          // your code here...
        }
```

Comment: If the code in the question compiled at all, it probably means that all the buttons were declared twice: once at class level and once in the method. So your answer goes into the right direction. But most likely, Will Scott-Jackson will just need to fix the `initButtons()` method the way you propose it.

Comment: Thanks guys that's fixed my problem :D Like you said, just declare it at a class level as opposed to method level and it's all working now! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

use the following pattern

```
public void initButtons(){      
    Button buttonOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    Button buttonTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_two);
    Button buttonThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_three);
    Button buttonFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_four);

    buttonOne.setClickable(false);
    buttonTwo.setClickable(false);
    buttonThree.setClickable(false);
    buttonFour.setClickable(false);

    buttonOne.setEnabled(false);
    buttonTwo.setEnabled(false);
    buttonThree.setEnabled(false);
    buttonFour.setEnabled(false);

    buttonOne.setAlpha(0.5f);
    buttonTwo.setAlpha(0.5f);
    buttonThree.setAlpha(0.5f);
    buttonFour.setAlpha(0.5f);

    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonThree.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonFour.ssetOnClickListener(this);


}
```

and let your activity implement onClickListener and have a switch case like this

```
 public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonOne :
// to do when clicked
        break;
    case R.id.buttonTwo :

        break;
    default :
        break;
    }
}
```

and inide your handler call

```
public void activateButtons() {
     buttonOne.setClickable(true);
   buttonOne.setEnabled(true);
 }
```

Comment: That's rather helpful for something I need to do later in my code thank you :)